# normalized 15-min absolute returns

Tags: return

I was reading an article today and I came across a new expression: "normalized 15-min absolute returns". I know what returns mean but I don't have any idea how I can normalize them ( I am not sure if they are talking here about the statistical normalization or not !!).

thank you guys ^^.

Comment: Yes, they are talking about statistical normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)

Comment: You are probably referring to Gabaix's article A theory of power-law distributions in financial market fluctuations, Nature (2003) http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v423/n6937/full/nature01624.html They measure returns in std dev units because some returns are more volatile than others.